# Use Psexec to get Connected USB Device names

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-8, psexec

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Psexec to return a list of connected USB Devices on remote windows 8 computers. Ideal output would be something like this:

- USB1: Keyboard
- USB2: Barcode Scanner

Obviously the device name would be displayed instead of 'keyboard' ect, is there an easy way to do this? I'm working within a secure environment with hundreds of remote machines, so unable to install any new Microsoft Tools such as Devcon myself.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: PsExec is a remote connection tool, it does not have any facility to determine the usb devices on those remote systems. You need to research methods of determining those devices externally of the remote connection tool.

Comment: `gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Sort Manufacturer,Description,DeviceID | Ft -GroupBy Manufacturer Description,Service,DeviceID` should get you started. It lists all USB devices on the local machine.

Comment: Once you work out what you want from DavidPostill's comment, you can use PowerShell `Invoke-Command` to run it on remote machines. No `psexec` needed.